# Passing Schema Manually to a Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

Question: **Is there a way to just pass the Column_names to a spark df and expect the spark to infer the schema types ?**

My Scenario: I'm trying to fire a **spark job** using Kubernetes that basically **reads CSV files from AWS S3** and creates a spark df using `spark.read.csv()`.

If there is **no header** for the CSV file, I need to pass the **schema manually** to the spark data frame, which I can achieve by the following approach.

```py
schema = StructType([
         StructField('column_name', StringType(), True),
         StructField('column_name1', StringType(), True)
       ])
df = spark.read.csv( csv_file, header = False, schema = schema )
```

That's all fine.

But

Problem: I'm passing the required parameters such as S3_access_key, secret_key, column_names ... etc as **environment variables** to the **executor pods**. Refer the below snippet.

```py
ArgoDriverV2.ArgoDriver.create_spark_job(
        's3-connector', 
        'WriteS3', 
        namespace='default', 
        executors=2,
        args={
            "USER":self.user.id,
            "COLUMN_SCHEMA": json.dumps(column_names),
            "S3_FILE_KEYS":json.dumps(s3_file_keys),
            "S3_ACCESS_KEY": params['access_key'],
            "S3_SECRET_KEY": params['secret_key'],
            "N_EXECUTORS":2,
    })
```

Using the column_names, I can generate the schema in the spark job and pass it to a data frame. But I find this approach a bit complicated.

**Is there a way to just pass the Column_names to a spark df and expect the spark to infer the schema types ?**

Comment: simply override the column names to use `df.toDF(*cols)`.

Comment: toDF() method is for RDD right ? I’m not creating any RDD, directly using read.csv method to create Spark DF.

Comment: it is not only for rdd i guess.

Comment: containers should be picked up their secrets from the IAM role of the container itself. If you do have to pass down secrets, consider creating session credentials (ideally for a restricted role, rather than your full account) and then passing down those secrets instead. Your IT admins will appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You could read the csv using `inferSchema=true` and then simply rename the columns like this:

```py
# let's say that we have a list of desired column names
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']

df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", True).csv("test")
df = df.select([df[x].alias(y) for x,y in zip(df.columns, cols)])
```

Comment: I found this in documentation ,cols = [ ‘col1’ , ‘col2’]         df = spark.read.csv( csv_file, header = False, inferSchema = True, columns = cols )

Comment: I could not find it in the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv.html). Also it does not work in spark 3.2. Can you tell me where you found that information?

Comment: My bad I mistook the pandas-on-spark dataframe for Spark Native Dataframe. You're right. Spark Dataframe doesn't have such option

Comment: So basically, you're doing a select statement for all the rows and putting an alias column name for the existing columns, right ?

Comment: Exactly. Basically just renaming the columns.

Comment: But that select statement will read through all the millions of rows once and will return it again if I'm not wrong. 
So just to rename columns should we read the rows twice once while read.csv() method and another while select statement.

Comment: Data is going to be read twice no matter what. Not because of the `select` but because you use `inferSchema`. Spark will need to read the data once to infer the schema and a second time to do your computation. However, spark is not going to read your data one more time just to rename columns. The select will not add any cost in IO or in computing.